Remove undefined results from Angular signals
imagine you have an observable which contains an object of an array  and mapping it to a signal with RxJS interop method toSignal().
data$: Observable<MyData[]> = this.dataService.getData();

dataSignal = toSignal<MyData[]>(this.data$, { initialValue: [] as MyData[]) });

This szenario has some strange conversation error on the initialValue option property.
Is it possible to convert it to a signal of MyData[] which don't have the type signal<MyData[] | undefined>?
Here is a StackBlitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fzwsff?file=src%2Fharry-potter-characters%2Fharry-potter-characters.component.html

Your stackblitz doesn't run, a file is missing

I changed something in it. Hope it's working now.

You can let the inference do its job to match the right function overload
Also for this to work you'll have to explicitly
toSignal(this.data$, {
    initialValue: [] as HarryPotterData[],
  });

or you can also specify the generics :
  data = toSignal<HarryPotterData[], HarryPotterData[]>(this.data$, {
    initialValue: [] as HarryPotterData[],
  });

